# git svn clone, mergeinfo are lost

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

We have a SVN setup which branch merge happens quite often. And I am currently trailing migrate to git. I am using svn2git for the migration, but I think the same does apply to git svn.

It seems that svn git clone will not retain mergeinfo from svn, as the result of svn and git merge working differently? For example, after dong `git svn clone` to migrate a svn trunk repositoy (with or without the feature branch). doing `git log --full-history` will only show the commit in the trunk where the branch been merged into, but all the commit history inside the branch which this merge introduced into trunk are not there anymore, but it does shows in svn repo if using TortoiseSVN and enable the 'Include merged reversions'. It seems that all the mergeinfo inside svn are not retained/copied into git master/trunk repository? Is it what supposed to happened?

I've read thatthat SubGit can handle that(I haven't tried it yet). But just want to make sure that git svn clone indeed not retain the mergeinfo propertiy/information from svn repository in git.

Comment: I have seen merges in Git produced by `git svn` already.

Comment: Merge is fine, just history not been keep from the merged branch, For example if a feature branch branched out from reversion 100 in trunk, and have commits 101 - 103, and trunk merged back the feature branch in reversion 104, in svn, I can see reversion history for 101-104, but in git, I can only see reversion history 100 and 104, the history from 101-103 in feature branch are lost in trunk after merge.

Comment: If you only clone the trunk this might be true. If you also clone the feature branch you would get the result you expect. At least I get exactly what you are expecting.

Comment: Thanks @Vampire, yes, I am currently clone with trunk and branch as well. So you are saying the mergeinfo does work for you?

Comment: Yes it does. :-)

Comment: @Vampire, are you using svn2git for KDE for the conversion, I found your other post regarding svn to git conversion, and you mentioned that, i am using svn2git ruby gems which as I understand just an script to simplified conversion by wrapping around git svn using ruby script. Which I would expecting will give me similar result as using git svn.

Comment: If you know my other posts already, you know my opinion to this topic already. But that had nothing to do with my comment. It stays true the same. For Git as frontend to SVN backend it is great.

Comment: @Vampire, thanks for your input, it turns out the main reason is that we have non-standard svn repo structure, trunk->app1, app2, app3, and branches->app1, app2, app3, I initially only cloned trunk which didn't bring merged reversions, and I later tried bring one branch only which doesn't work (I can't figure out a way bring a single branch from svn2git ruby gem interface), the last thing I tried was move the app trunk and repo to a new location in the same repo with standard layout, which seems working but missed all the merged reversion info.

Answer (score 0):

As @Vampire and others suggested from other places and SO Q & As: git svn probably not the best tool to import/convert svn repos, I am pretty sure it will works for certain cases. But fails mystery (to me anyway) in edge cases.

In our cases, it was because out non-standard repo structure, it has a shared root level trunk and branches for lots of different applications. So its structure looks like 'trunk\app1, app2, app3 ...', and 'branches\app1_feature1, app1_feature2, app2_feature, app3_feature1'.

Initially I didn't import any branches, which didn't bring the merged info from branch into trunk. I then tried to move the trunk and branch I need into different location in the same svn repo as standard structure, but git svn doesn't seems happy with that either. After that I tried [SubGit](https://subgit.com/) as it seems easy enough to getting started and is free for importing, but have no success initially as it's using the same moved trunk/branch. I then tried to use SubGit to import the whole 'branches' and finally got some of the merged infor back, but still missing some earlier revision info due to renamed/moved trunk.

At last I end up using ruby gem 'svn2git' with the following comment:

```
svn2git https://svn-host/product --trunk trunk/application1 --branches branches 
   --no-minimize-url --notags --metadata --authors ../../authors.txt -v
```

which as least brings the most recent merged info back and as a quick look, seems has all the revisions from trunk even with the renamed/moved old branch because the new trunk. But the conversion took really really long time, and I have to leave it running overnight, and it brings all the unnecessary branches from other applications into my git clone.

**Note**: For the comment I am using for svn2git, I later realized that the '--branches' parameter can be leaved out as 'branches' is the default value.

Comment: As the ` svn2git` you are using is based on `git-svn`, it of course needs ages as you surely know from my other answers. :-) Overnight is a good duration, for our work repository a fresh clone would need a week. If you would use KDE `svn2git`, the conversion would probably be done in 1 or 2 hours and you can easily adapt out to *any* layout. ;-)

Comment: 1-2 hours, so it is like 100 times speed up in your case! For me Its just looks like KDE `svn2git` a bit harder to getting started, but on the other hand, I am just starting to convert only one application, and I am currently documenting how I did the conversion, so I am planing to look at KDE `svn2git` soon.

Comment: I said "if *you* would use". I don't think that ours would be that fast, I didn't try yet. Yes, it is definitely harder to start, but it is definitely worth it.

Comment: Aha, missed that, must be wishful thinking on my side, imagine how disappointed if I find out later its is not even close to the speed up I claimed you've claimed :D

Comment: You will or would have an amazing speedup anyway, just maybe not that big. :-)